# Show $\{0^1^|≠\}$ is not regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, check-my-answer

So I have the question: show "Show $\{0^1^|≠\}$ is not regular". I've already seen various proofs for this question, but they all have one step I don't get.

They all take: $\bar{L}∩(0^∗1^∗)$ ($\bar{L}$ is the complement of $L$) and show that it's not regular. I don't get why we can't just take $\bar{L}$. Because isn't $\bar{L} = \{0^1^|m=n\}$ which is the same as $\{0^n1^n|n ≥ 0\}$ which we know is not regular? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to express in natural language what $\overline{L}$ contains; that is, what words $L$ *doesn't* contain. Most obviously, it's "words of the form $0^m0^n$, with $m = n$." However, it also contains "words that are not of the form $0^m1^n$", such as "$101010$". That's why the intersection with $0^*1^*$ is employed, to not bother with these words.

The demonstration is then possible because intersection and complementation are closed properties on the regular language. So if $\overline{L} \cap L(0^*1^*)$ is not regular, we know that $\overline{L}$ must not be regular, so its complement, $L$, must not be regular.

Answer (score 0):

Assume m ≠ m'. After processing $0^m$ and $0^{m'}$ you cant be in the same state, because in one state adding $1^m$ is not accepted and in the other state adding $1^m$ is accepted. Since is the case for all m ≠ m', the number of states is not finite.